# PHP $_GET leaves me url addon - how to get rid of it?

Tags: php, redirect, get, refresh

When button pressed:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
  <input type="submit" value="Truncate map">
</form>

if (!empty($_GET['act'])) {
  mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE mapinfo");
}
```

It redirects me to `index.php?act=run`

I want to get rid of it so added: `header("Refresh: 0; url=$page");`:

```
if (!empty($_GET['act'])) {
  mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE mapinfo");
  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header("Refresh: 0; url=$page");
}
```

but it first loads `index.php?act=run` than redirecting browser to `index.php` which makes 2 page refreshes.

How to do it the nice way?

Comment: You'd need to show the code for the form itself.

Comment: Added form code as you requested.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to let users clear out a table using just simply a GET request. It's better to manipulate the data only.

Comment: Its just for me, got tired of manipulating data only

Comment: That's fair enough, but even so, you might one day click refresh and lose a weeks worth of data... make it explicit and verified using a 'Are you sure?' alert before submitting the request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using a refresh header, use

`header("Location: $page");`

Answer (score 1):

Besides that there are some **major** security issues using this script, why not use the following:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
  <input type="submit" value="Truncate map">
</form>

if (!empty($_POST['act'])) {
    mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE mapinfo");
}
```

This will do a **POST** request instead of a **GET** request. However, please note that you still should redirect a user after a POST request ([Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)). Still, the request parameters are hidden.

**NOTE** Do not use these kind of scripts in production environments, they are far from safe!

Comment: @Lee: You are **absolutely** correct about the security, the POST request isn't safe; but note that it was not designed to be safe at all, it is designed to answer user1656447's question.

Comment: @user1656447 If I know the URL/address of your webserver, I can navigate to ....com/index.php?act=run and delete an entire database on your server. As far as I can see in your code there is no validation if the request originated from your own server, or if I even have sufficient rights to do this kind of action.

Comment: It's for my productivity, it's for localhost, this database getting truncated every few minutes of so. Anyway I could show you `echo` isntead of `TRUNCATE` to avoid this mess

Answer (score -1):

This is really the nicest way of doing it. You could unset the `$_GET['act']` variable so it doesn't affect the rest of the control flow, or just render the rest of the page like normal (i.e. you don't need the redirect, just render the rest of the page as if the `$_GET['act']` variable was never set).

Comment: -1 URL will be the same so. If you click "back" in browser you gonna truncate table again

Comment: I didn't think of that in this case. In any case, having a destructive operation as a `$_GET` request is a really, _really_ bad idea...